# First order algebraic structures: which are closed with respect to substructure formation?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory, universal-algebra

My instructor has presented a simple example in class.
Consider the structure $\langle \mathbb{Z},+,0\rangle$ where $+$ is interpreted as the usual addition. It admits as a substructure $\langle\mathbb{N},+\rangle$. Observe that the first is a group, but obviously not the second. Anyway we can indeed obtain the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}$ by viewing it as the structure $\langle\mathbb{Z},+,(\cdot)^{-1},0\rangle$ where we introduced a synmbol for the additive inverse. 
The same is not true in more articulate cases: such as if we view the field $\mathbb{R}$ as the apropriate first order structure $\langle\mathbb{R},+,\cdot,0,1\rangle$. Now we will not have a means to obtain subfields by simply adding new symbols to the language, as the multiplicative invers is not defined on $0$.

Can we generalize this problem? Can we say something about those structures which can be ''controlled'' by only adding symbols to their language, versus those which need explicitely axioms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes: an elementary class of structures (one that admits *any* axiomatization by sentences of first-order logic) is closed under substructures if and only if it admits an axiomatization by *universal* sentences (sentences of the form $\forall x_1 \dots \forall x_n\, \varphi(x_1,\dots,x_n)$, where $\varphi$ is quantifier-free).

As you noted, whether a class of structures admits a universal axiomatization is highly dependent on the language. For example, the class of groups in the language $\{\cdot,e\}$ requires the non-universal axiom $\forall x\,\exists y\, (x\cdot y = e\land y\cdot x = e)$. And indeed, not every substructure of a group in this language is a group. But if you add a unary function symbol $^{-1}$ for inverse, this axiom can be replaced by the universal axiom $\forall x\, (x\cdot x^{-1} = e \land x^{-1}\cdot x = e)$, and every substructure of a group in this language is a group.

In the case of fields, we actually *can* do a similar trick. View a field in the language $\{+,\cdot,-,^{-1},0,1\}$, where $x^{-1}$ is the inverse of $x$ when $x\neq 0$, and $0^{-1} = 0$. Then the class of fields is axiomatized by universal sentences. The inverse axiom is $\forall x\, ((x = 0) \lor (x\cdot x^{-1} = 1))$, and every substructure of a field in this language is a field. Of course, you could argue that this is not the most natural language for fields...

Going further, if you're not worried at all about sticking to a "natural" language, *every* elementary class of structures can be "fixed" in this way to be closed under substructures. The trick is to add *Skolem functions* to the language. For every formula $\varphi(x_1,\dots,x_n,y)$, add an $n$-ary function symbol $f_\varphi$ to the language. In the case $n = 0$, we add a $0$-ary function symbol, i.e. a constant. Now every (non-empty) structure $M$ in our elementary class $C$ can be expanded by the  Skolem functions in such a way that if $a_1,\dots,a_n\in M$ and $M\models \exists y\, \varphi(a_1,\dots,a_n,y)$, then $M\models \varphi(a_1,\dots,a_n,f(a_1,\dots,a_n))$. Having done this, any substructure of a model is an elementary substructure by the Tarski-Vaught test, and hence is (a Skolem expansion of) a structure in $C$.

I admit the above is unsatisfying in two ways: First, if you allow empty structures, and the empty structure is in $C$, then adding $0$-ary Skolem functions (constants) to the language removes the empty structure. Second, and more importantly, there might not be a *canonical* way to expand a structure in $C$ to include Skolem functions (this is in constrast to the groups case, where inverses are unique if they exist).